# Having trouble understanding how to test some things

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Not sure what I need to do here. I have private methods that make database calls to retrive values that are looked at and then return values to a caller. I've looked at Moq but I'm not so sure that's what I need.

An example of one of my methods is this:

```
    private bool ClientIdMatchesUserId(int userId, Guid clientId, out string message)
    {
        bool idsMatch;

        const string sql = "sql goes here";

        int result = (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(Connection, CommandType.Text, sql);
        if (result != 1)
        {
            idsMatch = false;
            message = "ClientId does not match.";
        }
        else
        {
            idsMatch = true;
            message = "ClientId matches.";
        }

        return idsMatch;
    }
```

The thing making this confusing for me is 1) I have a private method and 2) It has out parameters.

Is Moq what I need? Do I need to create a test database with known values?

I should add that I'm new to testing and could use all the advice I can get ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to unit test the class, you'll need to separate the database access from the business logic. At that point you can mock the dependencies and test the class through its public interface.

Here's one example of how that might be done.

```
public class User
{
    // properties map to columns
    // Consider using NHibernate, Entity Framework, etc.
}

// ALL database access goes through interface implementations.
public interface IUserRepository
{
    // One of several options - TryParse pattern
    bool TryGetById(int userId, out User user);
}

public class SomeBusinessLogic
{
    public SomeBusinessLogic(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public string ValidateClient(int userId)
    {
        // Probably more logic here.
        string message;
        bool result = ClientIdMatchesUserId(userId, out message);

        if (result)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return message;
    }

    private bool ClientIdMatchesUserId(int userId, out string message)
    {
        User user;
        bool found = _userRepository.TryGetById(userId, out user);

        message =
            found
            ? "ClientId matches."
            : "ClientId does not match.";

        return found;
    }

    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
}
```

Your tests would then look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void ValidateClient_WhenValid_ReturnsEmptyString()
{
    // Arrange
    const int UserId = 1234;
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var user = new User();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.TryGetById(UserId, out user)).Returns(true);
    var sut = new SomeBusinessLogic(mockRepo.Object);

    // Act
    string result = sut.ValidateClient(UserId);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(string.Empty));
}

[Test]
public void ValidateClient_WhenInvalid_ReturnsMessage()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var sut = new SomeBusinessLogic(mockRepo.Object);

    // Act
    string result = sut.ValidateClient(1234);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("ClientId does not match."));
}
```

I'd recommend reading [The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) to get a better understanding of this. It's a complex topic.

Comment: +1. Completely agree. BTW @user1064763, your database access would now live inside a class that implements `IUserRepository`, and you could test that with integration tests against a test database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out Moles.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx

Moq is used to Mock interface dependencies or dependencies that are public classes with default constructor and virtual methods.  Moles lets you mock basically anything and is specifically designed for mocking external dependencies like databases, files, etc.

Comment: I should also add that it's generally not a best practice to test private methods - you want to test the public interface of your class.  If you have a *lot* of private methods that you're having a hard time testing, that's a good indication that you may want to pull them into a separate class and make them public, giving your original class a private reference to your new class.

Comment: Interesting. But I'm now a little confused as to what value unit testing provides if I shouldn't test the lower levels of the code. Most of my private methods encapsulate functionality that the end-user shouldn't see ( such as business logic ) or simply the heavy-lifting. Then again, maybe I my idea of structuring isn't correct.

I'm going to check out that link right now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Unit testing is for testing your individual classes - if you had an "Adder" class with a public method "Add(int x, int y)", you would test that adding 2 and 5 gives you back 7.  The kind of testing that you're describing is "system" or "integration" testing - testing that your code interacts properly with some external entity.  You can provide seams for testing by splitting up your classes without exposing all of those seams to the end user.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I understand now. Obviously I've been looking at the wrong test type for my situation. This helps a whole bunch ;)

Comment: If you refactor your code as suggested in @TrueWill's answer, your database access code would live in a separate class (or classes), and you can write integration tests for those classes that use a test database.

Comment: @user1064763 You'll still end up testing the private methods, but you'll be testing them via the public methods. If you're testing an `Adder` class, you don't care *how* it does the adding, you care about whether the results are correct. It could be using the + operator, contacting a web service that does the addition, or executing a stored procedure that handles the adding on a SQL server. You have a black box, and all you care about is that when you put 2 and 2 into the black box, a 4 comes out.